# Start JasperReport subreport on new page, but not when launched as main report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a JasperReport named 'Receipt' that can be launched as a:

- subreport in a Summary band, to display any receipts
- main report, to display a particular receipt

How can I start a new page before any receipts, when it is used as a subreport, but suppress the new page if there are no receipts?

Setting isTitleNewPage="true" works when it is used in the subreport case, but causes the Detail band to be displayed on the second page when it is used as a main report.

Using a Break prior to the subreport means a redundant page is used if there are no receipts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by:

1. Adding a Boolean isSubReport parameter to the report
2. in the Detail band, adding a Break, with a Print When Expression set to:

   ```
   $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 && $P{isSubReport}
   ```
3. In the parent report, passing the parameter isSubReport with value TRUE()

Feels like there should be a cleaner solution, but it seems to work.